# React onChange function does not fire when passing it down to component

Tags: reactjs, input, state

Solved see comment below (Only had to move the Chooser and Section function outside of the class component to get it to work.

So I have a problem with the react onChange function. It does not seem to work when it is passed to a component as props. I tried to pass the component instead of the data but still it did not work. Please consider the following example:

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      type: '1',
      number: ''
    }
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    this.setState({ [name]: value })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <Form
            type={this.state.type}
            number={this.state.number}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
          />
      </div>
      }
  }


//receiving the props
export default class Child extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
        }

        render() {
            const Chooser = ({ type, section }) => {
                switch (type) {
                    case '1':
                        return <Fragment>{section}</Fragment>
                    default:
                        return <Fragment>></Fragment>
                }
            }
            const Section = ({ number, handleChange }) => (
                <Fragment>
                    <div>
                        <label>Number</label>
                        <input
                            type='text'
                            name='number'
                            placeholder='123456789'
                            value={number}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                </Fragment>
            )

            return (
                <Chooser
                    type={this.props.type}
                    section={
                        <Section
                            number={this.props.number}
                            handleChange={this.props.handleChange}
                        />
                    }
                />
            )
        }
    }
```

Interestingly if I put the onChange on the Section level it does work. But this is not what I want since a passed component could have multiple Input functions that I want to pass.

```
         return (
                <Chooser
                    type={this.props.type}
                    section={
                        <Section
                            number={this.pops.number}
                            onChange={this.pops.handleChange}
                        />
                    }
                />
```

Any ideas how I can pass the onChange function down using props? On a similar example the Input change does work but it is loosing focus each time a value is pressed. Already tried assigning keys but that did not work either.

Comment: can you share the code of the similar example of the input change losing focus that you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have this as your `handleChange` method

```
handleChange = e => {
  const { name, value } = e.target.value
  this.setState({ [name]: value })
}
```

You should change it to this.

```
handleChange = e => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  this.setState({ [name]: value })
}
```

You seem to be accessing the wrong property in the `target` because `name` will always be `undefined` inside `e.target.value` and as such, calling `setState` won't do anything.

Also, you should probably be declaring your function components outside of the class component.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I updated the example. The onChange function is working now but the Input field is loosing focus each time I am doing so.

Comment: Moving it outside the class component solved it thank you! Any explanation why exactly this is solving the problem?

Comment: This is probably because you're not able to track changes within the components you created inside of the render method. Once you make a change in the input field, the class component would re-render fully which was cause there to be no changes passed down because it will re-initiate the components in the render

Answer (score 0):

this is because you need to destructure it like this on the next like 
`const {handleChange} =   this.props.handleChange`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `handleChange()` in an anonymous function so that it will actively wait for you to make changes to the input. Otherwise it will run on render.

```
 const Section = ({ number, handleChange }) => (
                <Fragment>
                    <div>
                        <label>Number</label>
                        <input
                            type='text'
                            name='number'
                            placeholder='123456789'
                            value={number}
                            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                        />
                    </div>
                </Fragment>
            )
```

Comment: thanks for the contribution. It did not solve the 'loosing focus problem' of the input in my example, unfortunately. Any Idea for improvements would highly appreciate it!